# Extract relevant text from a .txt file in R

Tags: r, text-analysis

I am still on a basic beginner level with r. I am currently working on some natural language stuff and I use the ProQuest Newsstand database. Even though the database allows to download txt files, I don't need everything they provide. The files you can download there look like this:

```
###############################################################################
____________________________________________________________

Report Information from ProQuest 16 July 2016 09:58
____________________________________________________________




____________________________________________________________

Inhaltsverzeichnis

1. Savills cracks Granite deal to establish US presence ; COMMERCIAL PROPERTY

____________________________________________________________

Dokument 1 von 1

Savills cracks Granite deal to establish US presence ; COMMERCIAL PROPERTY

http:...

Kurzfassung: Savills said that as part of its plans to build...

Links: ...

Volltext: Property agency Savills yesterday snapped up US real estate banking firm Granite Partners...

Unternehmen/Organisation: Name: Granite Partners LP; NAICS: 525910

Titel: Savills cracks Granite deal to establish US presence; COMMERCIAL PROPERTY:   [FIRST Edition]

Autor: Steve Pain Commercial Property Editor

Titel der Publikation: Birmingham Post

Seiten: 30

Seitenanzahl: 0

Erscheinungsjahr: 2007

Publikationsdatum: Aug 2, 2007

Jahr: 2007

Bereich: Business

Herausgeber: Mirror Regional Newspapers

Verlagsort: Birmingham (UK)

Publikationsland: United Kingdom

Publikationsthema: General Interest Periodicals--Great Britain

Quellentyp: Newspapers

Publikationssprache: English

Dokumententyp: NEWSPAPER

ProQuest-Dokument-ID: 324215031

Dokument-URL: ...

Copyright: (Copyright 2007 Birmingham Post and Mail Ltd.)

Zuletzt aktualisiert: 2010-06-19

Datenbank: UK Newsstand

____________________________________________________________

Kontaktieren Sie uns unter: http... Copyright © 2016 ProQuest LLC. Alle Rechte vorbehalten. Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen:  ...

###############################################################################
```

What I need is a way to extract only the full text to a csv file. The reason is, when I download hundreds of articles within one file it is quite difficult to copy and paste them manually and I think the file is quite structured. However, the length of text varies. Nevertheless, one could use the next header after the full text as a stop sign (I guess).

Is there any way to do this?

I really would appreciate some help.
Kind regards,
Steffen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: What do you mean with  `... only the full text to a csv file ...`? The text after Volltext: only? And why you are using R and not Notepad++ and RegEx for your needs?

Comment: Yeah only the part after "Volltext". I am not sure how to use the RegEx in Notepad++, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have all publication information in a single text file make a copy of your file for reset first. Using Notepad++ and RegEx you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Choose the Mark tab.
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Find what: `^Volltext:\s`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to check `Bookmark line` (if unchecked only)
- Click on <kbd>Mark All</kbd>

[image]

From the main menu go to: Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked Lines

In a third step go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Find what: `^Volltext:\s` (choose from dropdown)
- Replace with: NOTHING (clear text field)
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Done ...

Comment: Awesome!Sorry for the late reply, got stuck with other work. But really appreciate your help. It works fantastic.

Comment: I'd be glad, when you upvote and mark as answered if this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
con <- file("./R/sample text.txt")
content <- paste(readLines(con),collapse="\n")
content <- gsub(pattern = "\\n\\n", replacement = "\n", x = content)
close(con)
content.filtered <- sub(pattern = "(.*)(Volltext:.*?)(_{10,}.*)", 
                        replacement = "\\2", x=content)
```

Results:

```
> cat(content.filtered)
Volltext: Property agency Savills yesterday snapped up US real estate banking firm Granite Partners...
Unternehmen/Organisation: Name: Granite Partners LP; NAICS: 525910
Titel: Savills cracks Granite deal to establish US presence; COMMERCIAL PROPERTY:   [FIRST Edition]
Autor: Steve Pain Commercial Property Editor
Titel der Publikation: Birmingham Post
Seiten: 30
Seitenanzahl: 0
Erscheinungsjahr: 2007
Publikationsdatum: Aug 2, 2007
Jahr: 2007
Bereich: Business
Herausgeber: Mirror Regional Newspapers
Verlagsort: Birmingham (UK)
Publikationsland: United Kingdom
Publikationsthema: General Interest Periodicals--Great Britain
Quellentyp: Newspapers
Publikationssprache: English
Dokumententyp: NEWSPAPER
ProQuest-Dokument-ID: 324215031
Dokument-URL: ...
Copyright: (Copyright 2007 Birmingham Post and Mail Ltd.)
Zuletzt aktualisiert: 2010-06-19
Datenbank: UK Newsstand
```