# Extract Relevant Text from a Chat Conversation

Tags: r

I have the below chat conversation:

*Chat Started: Monday, April 02, 2018, 10:23:30 (+0100) Chat Origin: GB - My Account (Signed In) Agent Navin P ( 1s ) Navin: Thanks for contacting XYZ, you are talking to Navin. How can I help?
( 34s ) Visitor: Hello , I?ve just currently switched from brillian broadband to fab fibre
( 39s ) Navin: Hi
( 42s ) Navin: Good morning.
( 47s ) Visitor: I find the brilliant broadband so slow
( 52s ) Navin: How can i help you today?
( 1m 1s ) Visitor: And we got told would be a day to get switched over
( 1m 5s ) Navin: I'll help you with it.
( 1m 11s ) Visitor: Can you tell me when this will happen by*

I am looking to extract only the relevant text from the above using **R.** I essentially want only the **Visitor** comments to be in the result.

The result I want is as follows:

*I find the brilliant broadband so slow
And we got told would be a day to get switched over
Can you tell me when this will happen by*

I tried to accomplish this using gsub and strsplit but to no avail. Appreciate inputs here.

```
mytext <- paste(c("Agent Navin P ( 1s ) Navin: Thanks for contacting XYZ, you are talking to Navin. How can I help? ( 34s ) Visitor:", 
    "Hello , I?ve just currently switched from brillian broadband to fab fibre ( 39s ) Navin: Hi ( 42s ) Navin: Good morning. ( 47s )", 
    "Visitor: I find the brilliant broadband so slow ( 52s ) Navin: How can i help you today? ( 1m 1s ) Visitor: And we got told would be", 
    "a day to get switched over ( 1m 5s ) Navin: I'll help you with it. ( 1m 11s ) Visitor: Can you tell me when this will happen by"
), collapse = ' ')
```

Comment: Possible duplicated of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410186/extract-relevant-text-from-a-txt-file-in-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: is your data row by row or the whole text is in single row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this. I split on visitor and used sub to remove Navin's answers.  For the substitution we need to add `[-1]` on the end because we don't need anything before the first "Visitor" that we split on.

```
str <- "Chat Started: Monday, April 02, 2018, 10:23:30 (+0100) Chat Origin: GB - My Account (Signed In) Agent Navin P ( 1s ) Navin: Thanks for contacting XYZ, you are talking to Navin. How can I help? ( 34s ) Visitor: Hello , I?ve just currently switched from brillian broadband to fab fibre ( 39s ) Navin: Hi ( 42s ) Navin: Good morning. ( 47s ) Visitor: I find the brilliant broadband so slow ( 52s ) Navin: How can i help you today? ( 1m 1s ) Visitor: And we got told would be a day to get switched over ( 1m 5s ) Navin: I'll help you with it. ( 1m 11s ) Visitor: Can you tell me when this will happen by"
str <- strsplit(str," Visitor: ")[[1]]
sub(" \\((.*?)\\) Navin:.*","",str)[-1]

# [1] "Hello , I?ve just currently switched from brillian broadband to fab fibre"
# [2] "I find the brilliant broadband so slow"                                   
# [3] "And we got told would be a day to get switched over"                      
# [4] "Can you tell me when this will happen by"
```

If you want a single line like your example you can use `paste`

```
paste(sub(" \\((.*?)\\) Navin:.*","",str)[-1],collapse = " ")
# [1] "Hello , I?ve just currently switched from brillian broadband to fab fibre I find the brilliant broadband so slow And we got told would be a day to get switched over Can you tell me when this will happen by"
```

If the name of the person is not consistently "Navin", you can use `\\w+` to match any person's name in the `sub` query to remove it.

```
sub(" \\((.*?)\\) \\w+:.*","",str)[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to retain more information:

```
mytext <- paste(c("Agent Navin P ( 1s ) Navin: Thanks for contacting XYZ, you are talking to Navin. How can I help? ( 34s ) Visitor:", 
    "Hello , I?ve just currently switched from brillian broadband to fab fibre ( 39s ) Navin: Hi ( 42s ) Navin: Good morning. ( 47s )", 
    "Visitor: I find the brilliant broadband so slow ( 52s ) Navin: How can i help you today? ( 1m 1s ) Visitor: And we got told would be", 
    "a day to get switched over ( 1m 5s ) Navin: I'll help you with it. ( 1m 11s ) Visitor: Can you tell me when this will happen by"
), collapse = ' ')


library(dplyr); library(textshape); library(stringi)

mytext %>%
    stri_replace_all_regex('(\\( [0-9ms ]+ \\))(\\s+)', '$1<<splithere>>') %>%
    stri_split_fixed('<<splithere>>') %>%
    lapply(function(x) {
        x %>%
            split_transcript() %>%
            mutate(dialogue = ifelse(!grepl('\\(\\s*([0-9ms ]+)\\s\\)', dialogue), paste(dialogue, '( - )'), dialogue)) %>%
            extract(dialogue, c('dialogue', 'timestamp'), '(^.+)\\s\\(\\s*([0-9ms -]+)\\s\\)')
    })

## [[1]]
##                  person                                                                  dialogue timestamp
## 1  Agent Navin P ( 1s )                                                             Agent Navin P        1s
## 2                 Navin      Thanks for contacting XYZ, you are talking to Navin. How can I help?       34s
## 3               Visitor Hello , I?ve just currently switched from brillian broadband to fab fibre       39s
## 4                 Navin                                                                        Hi       42s
## 5                 Navin                                                             Good morning.       47s
## 6               Visitor                                    I find the brilliant broadband so slow       52s
## 7                 Navin                                                 How can i help you today?     1m 1s
## 8               Visitor                       And we got told would be a day to get switched over     1m 5s
## 9                 Navin                                                    I'll help you with it.    1m 11s
## 10              Visitor                                  Can you tell me when this will happen by         -
```

Then you can filter by person etc.